# how do i count the total amount of active users from each database without creating another query?

Tags: php, mysql

So at the moment this code shows the active and inactive users from each database and dispalys them in a table how can i code something that shows the total amount of active users without creating another query

```
<?php
      
$data =  [];
$results = $con->query("SELECT systemname, identifier, value, date 
                        FROM kpi_log 
                        WHERE  CAST(date AS DATE) = CAST( curdate() AS DATE)");
while($row = $results->fetch_assoc()){
    $data[$row['systemname']][$row['identifier']] = $row['value'];
}

foreach($data as $key => $d){
    echo '<div class="card bg-light mb-3">
            <div class="card-header" style=background-color:dee2e6>
              <li>Systemname: '.$key.'</li>
            </div>
            <div class="card-body"style=background-color:dee2e6 style=color:red <div class="mt-4">
              <li>Letzter Login: '.$d['last_login'].'</li>
              <li>Aktive GPS Nutzer: '.$d['active_gps'].'</li>
              <li>Inaktive GPS Nutzer: '.$d['inactive_gps'].'</li>
              <li>Aktive App Benutzer: '.$d['aktive_app_benutzer'].'</li>
              <li>Aktive Backend Benutzer: '.$d['aktive_backend_benutzer'].'</li>
              <li>Inaktive Backend Benutzer: '.$d['inaktive_backend_benutzer'].'</li>
            </div>
          </div>';
?>
```

Comment: How do you determine active or inactive GPS? For a naive solution you could do another loop after creating the array, then moving them to an `$active_data` or `$inactive_data` array.

Comment: Its a table in mysql workbench that shows the active users so my code shows 2 tables with active user for example 100 active users and 150 active users in the other table i want to combine it but i dont know how

Comment: I should restate: Your question mentions "multiple databases" but your code only references 1 table. Also I don't see how that query shows you usernames. Also what does "active" mean in this context? You have two active/inactive properties --> GPS, App, Backend

Comment: so there is another code where it saves all the data from each day into a new table called kpi_log and yes i was talking about gps,app and backend